# accessing interface's overridden variable

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

Lets say I have an interface with a field - String type = "interface".
It's implementing class has a field - String type = "class".
Is there any way to access the interface's field through that class anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.. because basically interface variable are public static final or in other word, a constant..

you can access it in a static way using your

```
IYourInterfaceName.type
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public interface Firstone {
String type="interface";
}
public class Abc implements Firstone {

/**
 * @param args
 */
String type="class";
void check(){

    System.out.println("my class\t"+type);
    System.out.println("my interface\t"+Firstone.type);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Abc a=new Abc();
    a.check();
}
```

}