# How are Java objects which implement interfaces stored in memory?

Tags: java, inheritance, memory

Java doesn't have multiple inheritance of class, but it does support multiple implementations of interfaces for a class.

As far as I understand, when Java class inherits another class, its memory representation looks like this:

```
class Base {
    int x;
}

class Deriving {
    int y;
}
```

`Base` in memory:

```
vtable|Base.x
```

`Deriving` in memory:

```
vtable|Base.x|Deriving.y
```

Everything looks clear here as `Deriving` has to have all the fields `Base` has and all `Deriving`'s fields are stored right after `Base`'s ones.

But what happens when classes implement interfaces?
For instance, we have the following interfaces, which define same variable, and a class:

```
public interface Y {
    int x = 0; // both Y and Z have this field
    int y = 0;
    void methodY();
}

public interface Z {
    int x = 0; // both Y and Z have this field
    int z = 0;
    void methodZ();
}

public class A implements Y, Z {
    int a;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    public A(int x, int a) {
        this.x = x;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void methodY() {
        System.out.println("methodY: x = " + x + ", a = " + a);
    }

    public void methodZ() {
        System.out.println("methodZ: x = " + x + ", a = " + a);
    }
}
```

What happens when we have:

```
A a = new A(5, 6);
Y y = a;
Z z = a;
```

What do `y` and `z` point to and how do contents of `a` look like? How do vtables look and what do they contain?

The only thing I can guess is that it may look like this in memory:

```
A.vtable|A.a|Y.vtable|Y.x|Y.y
^ a          ^ y
```

meaning that `a` points to the beginning and `y` points to the middle of the object. But still I can't figure out how do interfaces share one field.

Comment: There is Y__x,  Z__x and A__x, one could be int, the other boolean and the third a String. I'm not sure your example compiles in Java, have you tested it?

Comment: @Dominique Lorre yes, I tested this code right before asking. Both methods `y.methodY()` and `z.methodZ()` work properly.

Comment: Ok don't have a java compiler to write a proper answer but read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305364/accessing-interfaces-overridden-variable)

Comment: Interfaces don't have instance fields. x, y and z in your examples are in fact static final fields. The instance fields in A hide the static final fields of the interfaces.

Comment: Okay, so `y.x` and `z.x` are just constants which don't depend on `a.x`. But what about vtables for the classes and interfaces? What happens if interfaces share a method?

Comment: If they share a method, the method in the class implementing both interfaces overrides both methods at the same time.

Comment: The most interesting part is what `y` and `z` point to

Answer (score 1):

Interface do not have Instant Variable, You can declare only method signature and static final constants in Interface.

```
public class A implements Y, Z {
    int a;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    public A(int x, int a) {
        this.x = x;
        this.a = a;
    }
```

Variable x and y will be treat as Local variables of Class A.

Interfaces and Classes will resides in PermGen in Heap Memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Interfaces do not have fields.  That should make the memory layout a lot easier.
2. The memory layouts will have each of the vtables in separate locations in memory.  Remember that vtables do not have the method implementations themselves, but a reference to where in memory the method starts.  That allows all methods to be at the correct place relative to the start of the vtable.

Comment: But what do `y` and `z` point to? How does JVM know where implemented methods of different classes are located?

Comment: Once the JVM has translated the bytecode into machine code, it will place the machine code in an area of memory over which it has control.